# Visual Studio Dock property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In my user interface, I would like to place two controls in the right side (a Treeview and Propertygrid). I want Treeview to grow and fill the right side space when the UI form  for is maximized. So when I set Treeview's docking property to right it overrides the Propertygrid as well. What actually I need is it should grow but it should not override propertygrid's space.

Am I missing any techniques?

Comment: Perhaps dock a split container Right, and then dock inside each of the panels (Full) your other two controls. Then you could adjust the size of your split container and insure that one control doesn't overlap the other.

Comment: I've made it a real answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps dock a split container Right, and then dock inside each of the panels (Full) your other two controls. Then you could adjust the size of your split container and insure that one control doesn't overlap the other.

Answer (score 1):

1.You may use 3 panels.A panel docks B panel that docks Treeview and C panel that docks Propertygrid.

2.Then set A panel dock right , B panel dock right and C panel dock fill.

3.Set Treeview dock fill.

4.Also,you may use 2 panels.A panel docks B panel that docks Treeview and Propertygrid.
  Then set A panel dock right. B panel dock right and Propertygrid dock fill.

5.Also,you may use 2 panels.A panel docks Treeview and B panel that docks Propertygrid.
  Then set A panel dock right. Treeview  dock right and B panel dock fill.

I suggest 3 panels.You can control better.

Comment: Using split container may solve the problem easy. See Brad Rem's answer